# Duplicate entry '0-0' for key 'local_part'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am making simple api to `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`.
Get works good, but I got problem with POST method.

When I am trying to post some data I am getting error:

```
    error:  Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '0-0' for key 'local_part'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    --------------------
    at Pool.query (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:199:23)
    at Function.Alias.create (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\app\models\customer.model.js:12:7)
    at exports.create (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\app\controllers\customer.controller.js:20:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\crud\nodejs-express-mysql-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) {
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry '0-0' for key 'local_part'",
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO aliases (local_part, domain, recipients) VALUES (`local_part` = 'team', `domain` = 'exmple.ag', `recipients` = 'tete@o2.pl')"
}
```

There is my model:

```
const Alias = function(aliases) {
  this.local_part = aliases.local_part;
  this.domain = aliases.domain;
  this.recipients = aliases.recipients;
};


Alias.create = (newAlias, result) => {
  sql.query(`INSERT INTO aliases (local_part, domain, recipients) VALUES (?)`,newAlias, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }
    console.log("created alias: ", { nr: res.insertNr, ...newAlias });
    result(null, { nr: res.insertNr, ...newAlias });
  });
};
```

and there is my controller

```
    exports.create = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
  }

  // Create a Alias
  const aliases = new Alias({
    local_part: req.body.local_part,
    domain: req.body.domain,
    recipients: req.body.recipients
  });

  // Save Alias in the database
  Alias.create(aliases, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Alias."
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

This is old db/table not created by me. 
I can't change anything in this table.
Also instead of ID is NR

**I also now that this value is unique and it's not duplicate. I can insert it by myself.**

There is table structure:

```
-- Table structure for table `aliases`
--

CREATE TABLE `aliases` (
  `nr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `local_part` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `domain` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'example.pl',
  `recipients` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Indexes for table `aliases`
--
ALTER TABLE `aliases`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`nr`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `local_part` (`local_part`,`domain`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `aliases`
--
ALTER TABLE `aliases`
  MODIFY `nr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2177;
COMMIT;
```

I think that there is problem

> ADD UNIQUE KEY `local_part` (`local_part`,`domain`);

but I don't have idea how can I solve it in node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to insert the data

```
sql.query(`INSERT INTO aliases (local_part, domain, recipients) VALUES (?)`,
     newAlias, (err, res) => {
```

is incorrect. Using your array directly translates to

```
INSERT INTO aliases (local_part, domain, recipients) 
VALUES (`local_part` = 'team', `domain` = 'exmple.ag', `recipients` = 'tete@o2.pl')
```

This does not insert the value `team` into the column `local_part`, but it inserts the result of the comparison `local_part = 'team'` into the column `local_part`. This should be `null`, but due to your sql mode this seems to give you a `0`. Same for the other columns, so you are ultimately inserting `(0,0,0)` into your table. Which fails the 2nd time because of the unique key, complaining that `(0,0)` already exists.

You can either use the [`set` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) where this array would work,

```
INSERT INTO aliases SET `local_part` = 'team', ...
```

by changing your code to

```
sql.query(`INSERT INTO aliases SET ?`, newAlias, (err, res) => {
```

or you can (or rather should) explicitly pass the parameters, e.g.

```
sql.query(`INSERT INTO aliases (local_part, domain, recipients) VALUES (?,?,?)`,
     [newAlias.local_part, newAlias.domain, newAlias.recipients], (err, res) => {
```

Comment: How it should be when I want to UPDATE ? I got same error ERR_DUP_ENTRY

Comment: Then I guess you did a similar mistake. You would need to show your code to narrow it down (preferably in a new question, but if it's basically the same problem, maybe here is fine too). My general advice to you is though: try to test-run your queries in a mysql client (console, phpmyadmin, workbench, ...) until it works, then replace all parameters (not column names) with ? (the format like in my last example) and put it in your app. Just in case the *rather should* in my answer got lost, I should maybe stretch that you should usually always use that last format (e.g. multiple ?, no array).